# How to test variable scoped in file, from unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, scope

I have a program like this

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 96
    a=A()
    print(a.foo)
```

When this runs from the shell "python foo.py" it prints out 96

I also have test_foo.py

```
import foo

import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        x=37
        a=foo.A()
        self.assertEqual(a.foo, 37)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this test_foo.py from the shell I get

```
$ python test_foo.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test1 (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 8, in test1
    a=foo.A()
  File "/home/zzz/foo.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.foo = x
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

So my question is, is it possible to test foo.py from test_foo.py, to set x and see it being used in the class A. f Without altering the foo.py program

Obviously, this is a simplified version of a real program

I get the same results with python 3.6 and 2.7

I have tried using various combinations of `global` but didn't find a way using this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` variable is defined inside the `if` block that checks if `foo.py` is being run as the main program, so when `foo.py` is imported by `test_foo.py`, `x` would not be defined, hence the error.

You should define `x` outside the `if` block instead:

```
x = 96

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=A()
    print(a.foo)
```

And in `test_foo.py`, if you want to override the value of the `x` of `foo`, you should do `foo.x=37` instead of `x=37` since `x` would otherwise be a local variable to `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.foo = x
```

and in the test:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        x=37
        a=foo.A(x)
        self.assertEqual(a.foo, 37)
```

Comment: Right, i could do that and it would work!   But imagine there are dozens of functions that use x.   I'd have to change them all.  If I was designing the program under test from scratch that's exactly what I'd do

Answer (score 0):

You make access to variable `x` in global scope here:

```py
        self.foo = x
```

When you run script directly `__name__` is '**main**', than you set global variable `x` and than construct `A()`.
When you import `foo` module code under `if` is not executed. There is no variable `x` in global scope nor in any outer scope.